# How to create virtualenv with bazel 0.24, then use that in py_runtime

Tags: virtualenv, bazel

I have an existing project that uses bazel 0.24. The project does not define a `py_runtime`. Right now, `py_test` targets can import items from `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` which breaks encapsulation and can cause version drift from what's defined in `requirements.txt`.

I cannot upgrade my bazel version at this time, so the toolchains work that's going on is not available to me.

I would like to define a bazel rule to build a virtual environment at `.venv/py27/...` using the `requirements.txt` file I have, so that I can use that environment in a `py_runtime`. I'll be doing the same with python 3.6 as well.

How can I express the creation of the virtual environment as a bazel target? Are there any special considerations for doing so and then using that as the runtime? How should the `py_runtime` be defined?